# How do I allow @replys to my tweets to show when tweet is expanded?

Tags: twitter

For all other twitter users, when I click on their tweet, if anyone has replied to that specific tweet, it shows up underneath in an expanded window. For some reason, none of the responses to my tweets are doing the same even though if I check in the mentions tab, there are responses there.

Is there a setting or some application I must install to allow other users to see responses to my tweets if they click on my original tweet?

My user name is @Fobwashed . It looks as though the only tweets that appear in a conversation underneath the original tweet are the ones I actually reply to but this doesn't seem to be the case with anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

If you've clicked on the "reply" link on twitter web, then twitter will understand that your reply is part of the conversation and will set an *in_reply_to*  that links your reply to the tweet.

If you just enter *@xyz this is my reply* then the *in_reply_to* link is not maintained & it won't be part of the conversation

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but that isn't the question I'm asking. People are clicking the reply button on my tweet but when you expand the tweet they are replying to, none of their replies are showing up. If I check in the mentions tab and click on their replies, my tweet appears above it to indicate the tweet it was in reply to, but if I go to my timeline and expand that tweet, their tweet does not show.